# How to redirect the root domain to a sub domain in AWS route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, dns, amazon-route53, cname

I'm using AWS route53 as my DNS server.

I have an A Record pointing a webserver for the sub-domain www and CNAME for the root "@" subdomain which points to the www sub-domain, so when I try to get mydomain.com or [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) I should get the same result and It works fine in [Godaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com/) DNS and [NameCheap](https://www.namecheap.com/) DNS servers but in route53 the www record works fine but the @ doesn't work and I have to type the full [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) for me to get the site back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you don't need to include the `@` symbol when creating record sets for your domain.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-basic.html#rrsets-values-basic-name),

> If you're creating a record that has the same name as the hosted zone, don't enter a value (for example, an @ symbol) in the Name field.